# Fetching data with javascript and sockets.io. Client side or Server side?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, sockets, fetch-api

Let's say that there is a project with multiple users that uses data from 3 database tables: Persons, Projects, Tasks.

There is a setup where a server listens for emit events and the client emits an 'update-[tableName]' event every time it changes some data on the database.

When the server receives and 'update-[x]' event, it broadcasts an event to all users, informing them what kind of data they need to refetch. So they all have their data updated every time a change happens.

My question is, is it a better method to fetch the changed data on the server and broadcast those to the users instead of an 'update' message? This way there will be only one request to the database instead for one request for every user. Are there any drawbacks on this method?

I tried the first method. Informing the users and let them fetch the data.
It works fine but I wonder if i can reduce the number of requests with the second method.

Answer (score 0):

You can absolutely do that! Instead of just broadcasting `update` to every client, you can attach the data with the broadcast. Let's demonstrate that:

server:

```js
socket.on('update-users', () => {
  const users = db.users.findAll(); // Replace this line with your code for fetching all users
  socket.broadcast.emit('update-users', users);
})
```

client:

```js
socket.on('update-users', updatedUsers => {
  setUsers(updatedUsers); // Replace this line with your code to update users in the client.
})
```

If you have better control on updates, you can even attach the id of the exact user that was updated and broadcast an update for the specific user. Example for how to do that:

client:

```js
socket.on('update-user' updatedUser => {
  setUserById(updatedUser.id, updatedUser); // Replace this line with the code to update the user in the client.
})

// This is used to emit an update for a specific user.
socket.emit('update-user', {id: '1'});
```

server:

```js
socket.on('update-user', ({id}) => {
  const user = db.users.findById(id); // Replace this line with your code for fetching user by id.
  socket.broadcast.emit('update-user', user);
})
```

Comment: Thank you for the reply.
In fact that's what I was thinking to do: send specific data about the update and broadcast back what is needed.

So there is not a problem doing the fetching on server side and broadcast them? That's great!

Comment: No, no problem at all! This should work perfectly.